# Nginx Custom error page for Individual directory

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, nginx-location

This my nginx configuration for 404 custom error page. But my problem is I'm getting custom 404 error page for all my 404 error that occurs in my server. I want to get custom error page for a particular directory only.

```
server {       
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    error_page 404 /fail.html;

    location = /fail.html {
        root /var/www/html/checking/errors;
        internal;
        }
    location /testing/([a-zA-Z]+)/ {
        root /var/www/html/testing/$1;
        try_files $uri $uri.html;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you're asking for is that when people attempt to view files of the form `/testing/does-not-exist` then they will see you error file, you want to move the `error_page 404 /fail.html` to within that location block.  Where you have it right now (within the server block), it will apply to all requests.  If it's for a different path that you'd like the error to show up, create a new location block for that path and then add the `error_page` directive to that block.